# Bug when editing date field in DataTable component

Tags: primefaces

I've got a weird bug when editing a date field using a Calendar component inside of an editable DataTable. To explain, I'm going to need to show you some pictures.

First, here is the actual page I'm working from:

[image: Base GUI]

Now, let's change date 1 in the list to the 13th of February and click OK.

[image: Date is changing]

As you can see, the table changes, but the row takes on another row's data.

[image: Date is wrong!]

Other than in the GUI, the update's gone just fine, and if we reload the page the date has been updated in the database. This is what the table looks like after the page has been refreshed:

[image: Date is correct in DB]

I've turned the code inside and out trying to get at this bug, and I'm starting to wonder if it's a bug in PrimeFaces itself. I've stepped through the entire workflow and have concluded that the backing ArrayList has the correct values at all times. I was thinking it may have had something to do with me sorting the list both when fetching it from the database and using the sortBy attribute of the DataTable. After disabling both however, the bug continues to manifest itself.

Here's my code for the page. Can anyone see anything I've done wrong? If so, you're my hero =)

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/standard-page-template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="title">Change Dates</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">

    <p:panel header="Change dates" style="width:760px">
        <h:form>

            <p:panel>
                    Just the search stuff here...
            </p:panel>
            <p:panel header="Search">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <p:dataTable id="listDatesTable" value="#{view.dateWrappers}" var="wrapper"
                                 rowIndexVar="index" editable="true"
                                 emptyMessage="Search for an ID above">

                        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{changePublishDateView.changeDate}"/>

                        <p:column headerText="Dragning" width="90">
                            <h:outputText value="#{wrapper.id}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Beskrivning" width="180">
                            <h:outputText value="#{wrapper.description}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Distribution" width="100">
                            <h:outputText value="#{wrapper.id2}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Publiceringstid" width="170" styleClass="#{view.duplicateDateInRow(wrapper)}">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{wrapper.newhDate}">
                                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                    <p:calendar
                                            mindate="#{view.minDate}" stepMinute="30" minHour="8" maxHour="22"
                                            pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" value="#{wrapper.newDate}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column width="50">
                            <p:rowEditor/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</ui:define>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this bug was due to the data in the individual rows being mostly identical.

Solution: Set a rowKey attribute on the datatable, to the date field. Now it works fine with or without sorting.

http://www.developer.am/primefaces/?page=RowKey